# Creating a Debian package with correct uninstaller

Tags: debian, linux-mint, packaging

I created a Debian package installer with a control file and desktop file, for a piece of software with no dependencies. It installs the software as expected, however the software does not seem to be removed when uninstalling with the software manager in Linux Mint. I am wondering if I am missing something i.e. how do I tell the package which files to remove? I don't have a postrm or prerm file. I created the package with:

```
dpkg-deb --build mydemopkg
```

The control file looks like:

```
Package: mydemopkg
Version: 1.0
Section: Office
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Maintainer: xxxx yyyy <xxx@yyy.com>
Description: My blah blah program
 for blah blah
```

Comment: Does `dpkg --remove mydemopkg` or `dpkg --purge mydemopkg` remove the package as expected? If not you will need to create prerm and postrm scripts for `dpkg` to run.

Comment: Yes, it does that (sudo dpkg --remove mydemopkg) with no errors. I guess the software manager needs something more.

Comment: By software manager you mean `apt`? or some kind of graphical tool? The reason it is not removing your package because it has not been indexed by your package manager. It does not know it even exists because you did not install it using it. Custom packages can be uploaded to a custom repository (which can be a local file directory) to be managed via `apt` but otherwise the tool you want is `dpkg`. Should I create an answer out of these comments or are you continuing to have issues?

Comment: Ah right. So I installed it by double clicking the ".deb" file, but I'm trying to uninstall with the software manager which is a graphical tool in Linux Mint. As I'm not putting the package in a repository I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay I will make an answer. Typically I complete all tasks like this via command-line but being able to double click a `.deb`, a custom built one at that, is pretty neat!

Comment: What does `dpkg -L mydemopkg` output, when the package is installed?

Comment: that's a very vague description of the problem.  What, exactly, do you mean by "the software does not seem to be removed when uninstalling with the software manager in Linux Mint"?     What have you done to investigate the issue?  Which (if any) files are being left behind when the package is removed?

Answer (score 2):

Custom packages, whether built by you or downloaded off the internet, are not maintained by your package manager without being set up to do so. However, the easiest way to manage one-off `.deb` files is via [`dpkg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg).

The relevant options for removing a given package are `-r` or `--remove` and `-P` or `--purge`.

The remove option removes everything but confiles. So you potentially do not have to reconfigure the software after re installation. The purge option removes everything related to that package that `dpkg` is aware of. If your package includes `prerm` and `postrm` script files they will be executed in that order as well during the package removal process when using `dpkg`.

Run either `dpkg --remove mydemopkg` or `dpkg --purge mydemopkg` to remove the package `mydemopkg`.

Comment: But that doesn’t explain why Software Manager isn’t uninstalling the software properly... It should end up using `dpkg` to remove the package, so there’s something weird going on.

Comment: @StephenKitt I understand that my answer as it stands does not directly address the question. I will work on getting that right.